# Is there some hidden message in the latest version's (1.106.1) update info?

Tags: ingress

Did anyone take a look into the update text of the [latest version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticproject.ingress&hl=en)? Is there some hidden message or something else in it?

```
FEATURES/FIXES v1.106.1  
* Attempting reinit 080483be <main>:  
80483be: 8d 4c 24 04 lea 0x4(%esp),%ecx  
80483c2: 83 e4 f0 and $0xfffffff0,%esp  
80483c5: ff 71 fc pushl 0xfffffffc(%ecx)  
80483c8: 55 push %ebp
```

Comment: It's definitely in assembly, just not sure which architecture it's for :/

Comment: The code is explained as the beginning of the main loop for x86 base processor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228261/understanding-the-purpose-of-some-assembly-statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the OWASP site](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack), this is just the first four lines of the second example of a buffer overflow attack. It doesn't look like it actually means anything significant.

```
080483be <main>:
    80483be:       8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
    80483c2:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
    80483c5:       ff 71 fc                pushl  0xfffffffc(%ecx)
    80483c8:       55                      push   %ebp
```

Credit to [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/50po0l/11061_with_wtf_whats_new/d761sdu) for googling.